# Libgdx Android – Read local file

Tags: java, android, libgdx

What is the correct way to read a local txt file in Android?

Using the code below, it works perfectly on Windows and some mobile phones, but in android emulators and older phones, it crashes.

```
public static FileHandle file2;
file2 = Gdx.files.local("data.txt");

if (file2.exists()){
}else{
    text_enc = Base64Coder.encodeString("My String");       
    file2.writeString(text_enc, false);
}
```

I tried using the code below, but it always returns true.

```
If (file2 == null){
    ....
}
```

The `file.exists()` has as note below. This applies in this case?
On Android, a `FileType.Classpath` or `FileType.Internal` handle to a directory will always return false. Note that this can be very slow for internal files on Android!

Comment: "... it crashes." Can you add the exception stack trace to the question?

Comment: I'm using BlueStacks and not have that information. How can I collect this information?

Comment: When your game crashes, an exception stack trace is shown in the log area. Simply copy that error information and paste it to your question.

Comment: I changed the code to: boolean exists = Gdx.files.local("data.txt").exists(); if (exists == true){ } and Work. Basically it's the same thing, but now worked.